# Setting a plain checkbox with robobrowser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

I am struggling to check a simple checkbox with `robobrowser` to discard all messages in mailman.

```
form['discardalldefersp'].options
```

returns `['0']`, neither

```
form['discardalldefersp'].value= True
```

nor

```
form['discardalldefersp'].value = '1'
```

delivers a result. I only get 'ValueError: Option 1 not found in field '

How can I set the checkbox?

My code for the whole thing is as following:

```
import robobrowser

pw = '<password>'

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open('<mailmanlist>')

form = browser.get_form(action='/mailman/admindb/<listname>')

form['adminpw'].value = pw
browser.submit_form(form)

form = browser.get_form(action='<listurl>')

form['discardalldefersp'].value = '1'
```

The HTML is the following (in German):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/images/mailman/mm-icon.png">
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>Administrative Datenbank</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="white"
dir="ltr">
<h2>Administrative Anfragen für Liste: <em>foobar</em></h2><!-- based on en 2.0 / StD-->
Diese Seite zeigt eine &Uuml;bersicht der gegenw&auml;rtigen administrativen
Anfragen f&uuml;r die <a href="https://lists.server.de/mailman/admin/foobar"><em>foobar</em>
Mailingliste</a>, die auf Ihre Genehmigung warten. Als erstes sehen Sie eine
Liste allf&auml;lliger Abonnement- und K&uuml;ndigungsanfragen, gefolgt von
eventuellen Nachrichten, die Ihre Genehmigung erfordern, und daher gestoppt
wurden.

<p>Bitte w&auml;hlen Sie f&uuml;r jede Anfrage die zu treffende Ma&szlig;nahme
aus, und klicken Sie auf den <b>Alle Daten senden</b> Knopf, wenn sie fertig
sind. Eine <a href="https://lists.server.de/mailman/admindb/foobar?details=instructions">detaillierte Anleitung</a> ist ebenfalls
verf&uuml;gbar.

<p>Sie k&ouml;nnen sich auch <a href="https://lists.server.de/mailman/admindb/foobar?details=all">Details</a> zu allen
gestoppten Nachrichten anzeigen lassen.

<FORM action="https://lists.server.de/mailman/admindb/foobar" method="POST" >
<center>
<INPUT name="submit" type="SUBMIT" value="Alle Daten senden" ></center>
<center> 
<INPUT name="discardalldefersp" type="CHECKBOX" value="0" >&nbsp;Alle mit     <em>Verschieben</em> markierten Nachrichten verwerfen.
</center>
<hr>
<center>

<h2>Zurückgehaltene Nachrichten</h2></center>

...

</FORM>
```

[image]

Comment: Done, I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message with a radio button. Try to add the option of '1' or True to the Robobrowser field **discardalldefersp** and see if it solves the problem:

```
form['discardalldefersp'].options = ['1']
form['discardalldefersp'].value = '1'
```

Or with the True option:

```
form['discardalldefersp'].options = [True]
form['discardalldefersp'].value = True
```

That solved me of getting the error message but the form didn't work well, but I think it was the web site that wasn't working good.